# Including a locally installed library in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, command-line-interface, arduino-cli

How do I include a local file? This is my project structure (with multiple sketches):

```
(project root)
    - some_config.json
    - SketchOne/
        - SketchOne.ino
    - SketchTwo/
        - SketchTwo.ino
    - lib/
        - lib_1/
            - some.h
```

From `SketchOne/SketchOne.ino`, I want to include `lib/lib_1/some.h`. I've tried the following(s):

```cpp
#include "lib/lib_1/some.h"
#include <lib/lib_1/some.h>
#include "lib_1/some.h"
#include <lib_1/some.h>
```

Note: I use the CLI (`arduino-cli`)

Comment: maybe it would be a better idea to use a SD Module. So later you can change data by replacing the SD-Card and reboot.
https://www.mischianti.org/2020/01/26/manage-json-file-with-arduino-and-esp8266/
Using a local JSON-File is not useful. You also could convert the JSON to an inline array within the program code. 
You can use https://quicktype.io/ to convert the JSON ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Arduino projects are called "sketches". The name of the main ino file of the sketch must match the name of the [sketch](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.27/sketch-specification/) folder. CLI builds one sketch at time.

Sketches are in file system organized into a folder called "sketchbook". The [sketchbook folder](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.27/sketch-specification/#sketchbook) should containing a special folder named "libraries". Folders in the libraries folder are treated as libraries. There are two forms of [library folder](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.27/library-specification/) in the file system: old and new.

See [the sketch build process](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.27/sketch-build-process/) too.

Comment: In that case, how can I include a file outside my "sketch" or is it not possible with `arduino-cli`. I feel like it can work but I need to play with `--library` and `--libraries` flag(s)

Comment: can't you put the library into the libraries folder? your folders structure listed in the question is similar to a sketchbook folder. why not make a sketchbook folder?